# many to many relation

Tags: sql, excel, join, union

I will be receiving 3 excel files each week. The first are projects from department A, with a Project_ID an x amount of columns. The second are projects from department B, again with a Project_ID x amount of columns. These projects are often related (many to many relationships) thus I will receive a third excel with a mapping of which projects belong to which projects. Later this process will be automated, therefore I'd like to attempt to create a decent `SQL` solution in advance.

My output should show related projects together as follows:

```
<br />Department A | Project_ID | Project name | etc
<br />Department B | Project_ID | Project name | etc
<br />Department B | Project_ID | Project name | etc
```

In addition, there should be an indication when a project does not have a mapping (yet).

I have tried:
Created a table for each excel file. Then full joined the Department A project to a project B so that all projects are in the table regardless of the link. However this result shows the related projects next to each other, not below. To further clarify I have created a small example [in excel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mk4mcheijbboj60/example.xlsx?dl=0).The tabs represent a file, the mapping or the output.

Hope you'll be able to give me the right push! Thanks

Comment: Does the mapping have two PROJECT_IDs too? If so, you can just join them. What is the problem?

Comment: Because In my output I need them below each other. And indicate when such a combination could not be made.

Comment: In that case, please be more clear on what you have tried and what the output should look like. Please give explicit examples for those edge cases where there is, for instance, no relation or multiple relations across a group of projects.

Comment: Based on your example spreadsheet, all the information in the Expected Output is contained in the Mapping tab, just presented in a different format. The Department A and Department B tabs don't appear to add anything and appear to be inconsistent - Project 6 is associated with 136658 in Department A but with 136659 in Mapping and Expected Output. There is a similar inconsistency with Name 6 in the Department B. So, what does the information in Department A and Department B provide beyond that available from Mapping?

Comment: Well those tables also contain information about project status, budget, planning etc, but I have omitted this information since it is not key to my problem. Btw I've updated the excel for a better example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you'd like to use `union all`, not join:

```
SELECT 'Department A', id, name
FROM   projects_a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Department B', id, name
FROM   projects_b
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Department C', id, name
FROM   projects_c
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Department D', id, name
FROM   projects_d
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but then how will I manage to group the related projects over the departments? thnx for your reply